# Adding variable columns and values to empty list

Tags: r, list, variables, append

I am trying to iterate through different datasets, extracting numbers from them. The name of each dataset is used as column of a list, the numbers should be added to the column. Just like in this example this does not work:

```
> liste<-list()
> for (i in c("di","mi","do")){print(i); liste$i<-c(liste$i,4)}
[1] "di"
[1] "mi"
[1] "do"
> liste
$i
[1] 4 4 4
```

Starting with an empty list, I want to add a column called "di", and add the value 4 (lateron more values) to that column. However, R doesn't use the variable, but calls all columns `i`. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[` instead of `$`:

```
liste<-list()
for (i in c("di","mi","do")){print(i); liste[[i]]<-4}
liste
```